# How to use split for CSV while escaping \

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to split a csv list.
**csvList=hello there, how are you, what is your name\, again**

I have to use the Java split function to get the three components:

```
hello there
how are you
what is your name, again
```

I want to escape the comma that is preceded by the '\'.
Can anyone please help?

Thanks.

Comment: @hd1 OP don't want to split on `,` if it has ``\`` before.

Comment: Oops, misunderstood, apologies, it's been deleted

Answer (score 3):

You can use lookbehind egex:

```
String[] tok="hello there, how are you, what is your name\\, again".split(" *(?<!\\\\), *");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [negative look behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) like this:

```
input.split("\\W*(?<!\\\\),\\W*")
```

Really the key here is the `(?<!\\\\),`.  This says, "Find me comma's that don't have a slash behind them."

You need 4 slashes because in Java, the first slash will be considered an escape (eg: like the slash for `\t`).  Two slashes will be considered as slash, but in a regex, a slash is a special character.  So you need to escape the escape.

The `\\W*` says, "match 0 or more whitespace characters".  The point of that is simply to trim your results so they don't have spaces before or after them.